# Xcode 5 iOS7 - too many ScriptAgent processes

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5, xcode-instruments

Running UIAutomation scripts using xcode-instruments creates duplicate processes like this:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/ScriptAgent

These processes can't be killed and only system reboot will kill them.
Also, the script is stopped and these lines are printed:

```
2013-10-23 14:54:57.850 ScriptAgent[35342:2d07] CLTilesManagerClient: initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient 
2013-10-23 14:54:57.850 ScriptAgent[35342:2d07] CLTilesManagerClient: init 
2013-10-23 14:54:57.851 ScriptAgent[35342:2d07] CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting, 0x962eef0
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How are you trying to kill them?

Comment: 1. ps aux | grep ScriptAgent
2. sudo kill -9 pid

Comment: This doesn't seem to kill them

Comment: I can confirm that `sudo kill -9` on these PIDs does nothing.  Same situation for the multiple instances of xpcproxy_sim.

Comment: Found the fix, posting answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to kill the parent process of these zombie processes, and they will go away.  This works in Mavericks and Xcode 5.1, at least:

```
$ ps -edf | \
grep [x]pcproxy_sim | awk '{print $3}' | \
sort | uniq | \
xargs -I{} echo "kill -9 {}" | sh
```

The first line lists all processes.  The second line extracts the `PPID` column (parent PID) of `xpcproxy_sim` processes.  The third line removes duplicate entries, and the last line generates the command to kill each process and passes it to a shell for execution.